# JSON and XML Serialization

Tags: c#, json, xml, database, winforms

Can someone explain how to use JSON and XML Serialization to store and transfer data and generalized situations in which you would choose one over the other?

Comment: Do you want to store data in a file that has limited access or do you want to store in the Server (like SQL Server database) that has access to the internet?

Comment: Sorry, I'll include a more detailed question. The application will be accessed by multiple users (10-15), with some users with administrative roles and others with only the ability to view the database. It will be deployed across multiple desktops.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't the right vehicle for questions of the form "please explain technology X to me from first principles." The right place to take that question is a bookshop.

Comment: Wasn't asking for a complete explanation, was just asking for a better understanding. However, an answer would of been helpful.

Comment: Multi-user data should never be shared in an xml file on a file system.  If it is read-only it could be posted on a URL.  It would be better to put nto a database.  SQL Server Express can be download from msdn for free and would meet your requirements.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for actually answering my question. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML & JSON are not to be used to store data, but rather transfer data between different pages, forms or web services. That's what they were designed for in the first place.

Differences between JSON and XML:

**Similarities:**

- Both JSON and XML are "self describing" (human readable)
- Both JSON and XML are hierarchical (values within values)
- Both JSON and XML can be parsed and used by lots of programming languages
- Both JSON and XML can be fetched with an XMLHttpRequest

**Differences:**

- JSON doesn't use end tag
- JSON is shorter
- JSON is quicker to read and write
- JSON can use arrays

You can find several explanations and guides on both XML and JSON in the links below. Make sure you give them a brief read before deciding on your preferred approach.

To your original question, I would suggest storing your user information in a separated database. There are many options out there for you to go through and decide what fits you best, considering your initial requirements.

> XML:
>
> https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_whatis.asp
>
> https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_usedfor.asp
>
> JSON:
>
> http://www.json.org/
>
> https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp
>
> Source:
>
> https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_xml.asp

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Several prolific databases are supporting the storage of JSON formatted text with query support built in.